# Standard Deviation - % of Products Sold

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, standard-deviation

I am trying to work out the standard deviation and RSD of a set of percentages.
The percentages refer to the sellthrough of products across a number of stores e.g.

Product 1

Store 1 - Opening stock - 10, sold - 7, 70% sold.

Store 2 - Opening stock - 20, sold - 14, 70% sold.

Store 3 - Opening stock - 30, sold - 21, 70% sold.

Store 4 - Opening stock - 40, sold - 20, 50% sold.

Is it fair to say that the standard deviation of the % sold = 0.1 and the RSD = 15% or is there a different method or interpretation when performing calculation of SD & RSD on a set of percentages? Should I be applying a weighting before calculating the mean?

The goal is to identify which stores perform well or not so well with certain products or within certain ranges of products. The opening stock will vary in each case, in reality the difference would be thousands of units between stores and thousands of units in sales.

I appreciate any feedback.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show how you got the numbers ?

Comment: I got SD using the STDEV.S function in excel 2013, selecting the percentages only. RSD was (SD/Mean)*100.

Comment: I have a different result: $\sqrt{(3\cdot (0.7-0.65)^2+(0.5-0.65)^2)/\color{red}4)}=8.66\%$. Excel used the formula for the estimated standard deviation of a sample with $\color{red}3$ in the denominator.

Comment: Beside this I don´t know what the standard deviation between the stores has to do with comparing the perfomance of the stores. Comparing the standard deviations of the stores might be interesting. There are many concepts which can be used. One is to compare the ratio of sales and the opening stock. In this case the perfomance of the store 4 is the worst with $50\%$. Store 4 should reduce there orders for the next period could be a consequence of this result. But there are other operating figues which can be compared like return on sales.

Comment: We normally look at more concrete metrics, like ratio of sales, distribution within regions, but my supervisor found an old spreadsheet with standard deviation on it as a measure of sell through. I was just concerned that getting SD of percentages may not be a real indicator of performance as it doesn't really take into account actual sales and thought that a weighting would be needed. Thanks for your help, I'm trying to branch out in stats and I'm sure I'll gain more insight as I move along.